# How to use a path variable in PowerShell when executing from VSTS/Azure to write to VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell which exports some Azure Services (pure script files for creating Microsoft Azure Resources). I am able to execute thos scripts from within VSTS when using `Azure PowerShell` in a Release definition.

[image]

This script executes the relevant API and writes the result "normally" to a local drive or azure storage.

But i want to export to a VSTS folder. Normally there is a so called drop folder where for example build results are stored.

```
$pathToExport = "c:\mytempfolder\db\Cluster\" ... 
$export = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AzureResourceExportApiUrl -Method GET -Headers $headers -Body 
$parameters $export | ConvertTo-JSON -depth 100 | Out-File $pathToExport
```

Is there a way to use VSTS folders?

Comment: did you try `Agent.ReleaseDirectory` or `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory` automatic variable? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drop folder is used for build instead of release, so you can’t do it as in VSTS build.

You may upload the file to source repository of VSTS through REST API: [Add a binary file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pushes/create?view=vsts-rest-4.1#add_a_binary_file)